A wall of red errors when testing MUI Datagrid
I am introducing tests into my project and the thing I've encountered is that when I test the whole page component MUI datagrid table gives a wall of errors making it almost impossible to understand what is exactly wrong.
As I understand it, it has something to do with my table being resized in useEffect. Also I have set some autosize props and if I comment out these props and the useEffect the red wall goes away during tests. How do I fix this?
I tried wrapping render method in await waitFor which makes errors go away but I don't think it's the right way to do it since my IDE shows me this: "Avoid using side effects within waitFor callback"
MUI version:
"@mui/material": "^5.15.21",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.8.0",
Here's the table component:
import { DataGrid, useGridApiRef } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { ruRU } from "@mui/x-data-grid/locales";
import { rowsPerPage } from "constants/constants";
import { useDetailsCard } from "hooks/useDetailsCard";
import { useGetTableData } from "hooks/useGetTableData";
import { useSelectedItemsCard } from "hooks/useSelectedItemsCard";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { OrderTableStyles } from "./ContentTableBodyStyles";

const ContentTableBody = ({ paginationModel, handlePagination }) => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const { isFetching, data, dataItem, columns, isInvoices } = useGetTableData();

  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  const { openDetailsCard, closeDetailsCard, setOrderId } = useDetailsCard();

  const {
    openSelectedCard,
    setDeliveriesToExport,
    closeSelectedCard,
    rowSelectionModel,
    setRowSelectionModel,
  } = useSelectedItemsCard(apiRef);

  const openOrderCard = ({ id }) => {
    setOrderId(id - 1);
    openDetailsCard();
  };

  const handlePageSize = ({ pageSize, page }) => {
    handlePagination({
      page: paginationModel.pageSize !== pageSize ? 0 : page,
      pageSize: pageSize,
    });
  };

  const handleRowSelection = (rowIds) => {
    setRowSelectionModel(rowIds);

    if (isInvoices) return;

    const deliveryIds = rowIds
      .filter((rowId) => data.results[rowId - 1].deliveries.length)
      .map((rowId) => data.results[rowId - 1].deliveries[0].deliveryId);

    setDeliveriesToExport(deliveryIds);

    if (rowIds.length) {
      openDetailsCard();
      openSelectedCard();
    }
    if (!rowIds.length) {
      closeSelectedCard();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    closeDetailsCard();
  }, [closeDetailsCard]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) {
      apiRef.current.autosizeColumns({
        includeHeaders: true,
        includeOutliers: true,
      });
    }
  }, [isFetching, apiRef]);

  const rows = data?.results.map((item, index) => dataItem(item, index)) || [];

  return (
    <DataGrid
      autosizeOptions={{
        includeOutliers: true,
        includeHeaders: true,
      }}
      autosizeOnMount
      autoHeight
      checkboxSelection
      disableRowSelectionOnClick
      disableColumnMenu
      disableColumnResize
      rowCount={data?.count || 0}
      paginationMode="server"
      columnHeaderHeight={40}
      rows={rows}
      loading={isFetching}
      apiRef={apiRef}
      columns={columns}
      getRowHeight={() => "auto"}
      pageSizeOptions={rowsPerPage}
      onRowClick={openOrderCard}
      sortingOrder={["desc", "asc", null]}
      initialState={{
        pagination: {
          paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 10 },
        },
      }}
      paginationModel={paginationModel}
      onPaginationModelChange={handlePageSize}
      onRowSelectionModelChange={handleRowSelection}
      rowSelectionModel={rowSelectionModel}
      sx={OrderTableStyles}
      localeText={
        i18n.language === "ru"
          ? ruRU.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText
          : null
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ContentTableBody;

And here's a snippet of the error since all of it doesn't fit in the terminal:
at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\DataGrid\DataGrid.js:27:55)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTableBody\ContentTableBody.jsx:11:29)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTable.jsx:9:52)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Paper\Paper.js:70:43)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\LeftGrid.jsx:4:21)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\MainContentGridContainer.jsx:3:37)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\PageTypeProvider.js:5:36)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\createBox.js:31:40)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\PageWrapper.jsx:3:24)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Pages\OrderList.jsx:19:33)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\AuthProvider.js:5:32)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router\lib\components.tsx:413:13)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router-dom\index.tsx:774:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\DefaultPropsProvider\DefaultPropsProvider.js:18:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\RtlProvider\index.js:19:7)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\private-theming\node\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:39:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:52:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\styles\ThemeProvider.js:21:14)
        at Suspense
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-redux\src\components\Provider.tsx:58:3)

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:7)
      at warnIfUpdatesNotWrappedWithActDEV (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27628:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25547:5)
      at setState (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16708:7)
      at l (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/utils/useGridSelector.js:50:9)
      at forEach (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:35)
          at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Store.update (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:22)
      at Object.setState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/core/useGridStateInitialization.js:63:28)
      at setGridColumnsState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:56:20)
      at Object.updateColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:99:5)
      at Object.autosizeColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columnResize/useGridColumnResize.js:524:22)

  console.error
    Warning: An update to ForwardRef(DataGrid) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\DataGrid\DataGrid.js:27:55)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTableBody\ContentTableBody.jsx:11:29)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTable.jsx:9:52)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Paper\Paper.js:70:43)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\LeftGrid.jsx:4:21)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\MainContentGridContainer.jsx:3:37)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\PageTypeProvider.js:5:36)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\createBox.js:31:40)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\PageWrapper.jsx:3:24)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Pages\OrderList.jsx:19:33)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\AuthProvider.js:5:32)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router\lib\components.tsx:413:13)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router-dom\index.tsx:774:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\DefaultPropsProvider\DefaultPropsProvider.js:18:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\RtlProvider\index.js:19:7)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\private-theming\node\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:39:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:52:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\styles\ThemeProvider.js:21:14)
        at Suspense
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-redux\src\components\Provider.tsx:58:3)

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:7)
      at warnIfUpdatesNotWrappedWithActDEV (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27628:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25547:5)
      at setState (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16708:7)
      at l (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/utils/useGridSelector.js:50:9)
      at forEach (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:35)
          at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Store.update (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:22)
      at Object.setState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/core/useGridStateInitialization.js:63:28)
      at node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/dimensions/useGridDimensions.js:79:20
      at setDimensions (node_modules/@mui/utils/node/useEventCallback/useEventCallback.js:25:18)
      at Object.call [as current] (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/dimensions/useGridDimensions.js:200:5)
      at EventManager.apply (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/utils/useGridApiEventHandler.js:43:11)
      at EventManager.emit (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/EventManager.js:57:18)
      at Object.publishEvent (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/core/useGridApiInitialization.js:97:40)
      at setGridColumnsState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:57:20)
      at Object.updateColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:99:5)
      at Object.autosizeColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columnResize/useGridColumnResize.js:524:22)

  console.error
    Warning: An update to GridScrollAreaRaw inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\GridScrollArea.js:62:5)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\virtualization\GridMainContainer.js:26:74)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\virtualization\GridVirtualScroller.js:60:58)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\containers\GridRoot.js:43:59)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\context\GridContextProvider.js:15:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\DataGrid\DataGrid.js:27:55)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTableBody\ContentTableBody.jsx:11:29)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTable.jsx:9:52)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Paper\Paper.js:70:43)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\LeftGrid.jsx:4:21)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\MainContentGridContainer.jsx:3:37)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\PageTypeProvider.js:5:36)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\createBox.js:31:40)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\PageWrapper.jsx:3:24)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Pages\OrderList.jsx:19:33)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\AuthProvider.js:5:32)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router\lib\components.tsx:413:13)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router-dom\index.tsx:774:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\DefaultPropsProvider\DefaultPropsProvider.js:18:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\RtlProvider\index.js:19:7)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\private-theming\node\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:39:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:52:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\styles\ThemeProvider.js:21:14)
        at Suspense
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-redux\src\components\Provider.tsx:58:3)

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:7)
      at warnIfUpdatesNotWrappedWithActDEV (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27628:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25547:5)
      at setState (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16708:7)
      at l (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/utils/useGridSelector.js:50:9)
      at forEach (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:35)
          at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Store.update (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:22)
      at Object.setState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/core/useGridStateInitialization.js:63:28)
      at node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/dimensions/useGridDimensions.js:79:20
      at setDimensions (node_modules/@mui/utils/node/useEventCallback/useEventCallback.js:25:18)
      at Object.call [as current] (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/dimensions/useGridDimensions.js:200:5)
      at EventManager.apply (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/utils/useGridApiEventHandler.js:43:11)
      at EventManager.emit (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/EventManager.js:57:18)
      at Object.publishEvent (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/core/useGridApiInitialization.js:97:40)
      at setGridColumnsState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:57:20)
      at Object.updateColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:99:5)
      at Object.autosizeColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columnResize/useGridColumnResize.js:524:22)

  console.error
    Warning: An update to GridScrollAreaRaw inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\GridScrollArea.js:62:5)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\virtualization\GridMainContainer.js:26:74)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\virtualization\GridVirtualScroller.js:60:58)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\components\containers\GridRoot.js:43:59)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\context\GridContextProvider.js:15:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\node\DataGrid\DataGrid.js:27:55)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTableBody\ContentTableBody.jsx:11:29)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\ContentTable\ContentTable.jsx:9:52)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Paper\Paper.js:70:43)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\LeftGrid.jsx:4:21)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Grid\Grid.js:381:48)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\MainContentGridContainer.jsx:3:37)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\PageTypeProvider.js:5:36)
        at div
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b1930563.cjs.js:73:23)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\createBox.js:31:40)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Components\UI\PageComponents\PageWrapper.jsx:3:24)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\Pages\OrderList.jsx:19:33)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\src\context\AuthProvider.js:5:32)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router\lib\components.tsx:413:13)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-router-dom\index.tsx:774:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\DefaultPropsProvider\DefaultPropsProvider.js:18:3)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\RtlProvider\index.js:19:7)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\private-theming\node\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:39:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\system\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:52:5)
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\@mui\material\node\styles\ThemeProvider.js:21:14)
        at Suspense
        at fn (C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\react-redux\src\components\Provider.tsx:58:3)

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:7)
      at warnIfUpdatesNotWrappedWithActDEV (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27628:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25547:5)
      at setState (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16708:7)
      at l (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/utils/useGridSelector.js:50:9)
      at forEach (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:35)
          at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Store.update (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/Store.js:25:22)
      at Object.setState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/core/useGridStateInitialization.js:63:28)
      at node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/dimensions/useGridDimensions.js:79:20
      at setDimensions (node_modules/@mui/utils/node/useEventCallback/useEventCallback.js:25:18)
      at Object.call [as current] (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/dimensions/useGridDimensions.js:200:5)
      at EventManager.apply (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/utils/useGridApiEventHandler.js:43:11)
      at EventManager.emit (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/utils/EventManager.js:57:18)
      at Object.publishEvent (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/core/useGridApiInitialization.js:97:40)
      at setGridColumnsState (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:57:20)
      at Object.updateColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columns/useGridColumns.js:99:5)
      at Object.autosizeColumns (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/node/hooks/features/columnResize/useGridColumnResize.js:524:22)

Here's the test file, but the table itself buried deep in the layout, so might not be informative:
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Loader from "Components/UI/Loader/Loader";
import { AuthProvider } from "context/AuthProvider";
import OrderList from "Pages/OrderList";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { store } from "reduxStore/store";
import { theme } from "Theme";
// import * as api from "../../reduxStore/api/orderListApiSlice";

beforeEach(() => {
  //   jest.spyOn(console, "error");
  //   console.error.mockImplementation(() => null);

  localStorage.setItem("userId", "991d3a3a-6e71-4869-9861-2b897d7a9deb");
  localStorage.setItem(
    "default-customer-991d3a3a-6e71-4869-9861-2b897d7a9deb",
    JSON.stringify({
      customerId: "eu.33008274",
      customerNumber: "33008274",
      customerName: 'ООО "АДАМАНТ СПб"',
      street: "Глухоозерское ш.,д.12,лит.А,пом.8-Н,оф.2",
      postalCode: "Глухоозерское ш.,д.1",
      city: "г.Санкт-Петербург",
      state: "78",
      countryId: "RU",
    })
  );
});

afterEach(() => {
  //   console.error.mockRestore();
});

jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str) => str,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
}));

jest.mock("hooks/useIsComponentEnabled", () => ({
  useIsComponentEnabled: () => ({
    getIsComponentEnabled: () => jest.fn(true),
    isSuccess: true,
  }),
}));

describe("OrderList", () => {
  it("renders table correctly", async () => {
    // const spy = jest.spyOn(api, "useGetOrderListQuery");
    // spy.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: testOrderData, isLoading: false });

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <AuthProvider>
                <OrderList />
              </AuthProvider>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Suspense>
      </Provider>
    );

    // const text = await screen.findByText("1–1 of 1");
    // await waitFor(
    //   () => {
    //     expect(text).toBeInTheDocument();
    //   },
    //   { timeout: 10000 }
    // );

    expect(screen.getByRole("grid")).toBeInTheDocument();

    screen.debug(undefined, 10000000);
  });
});


For now fixed it by wrapping debug in waitFor:
await waitFor(() => {
      screen.debug(undefined, 10000000);
    });

